# lame.exe on all wavs in a folder with .bat

Tags: batch-file, lame

I would like to write a batch file that runs the cmd line 
" lame.exe [options] [infile] [outfile]"
on a folder of .wav files.

something like

FOR %%f IN (dir *.wav) DO (lame.exe -V0 -h %%f.wav %%f.mp3)

of course that's wrong but...how do I generate  the correct  [infile] [outfile] arguments for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the above, and got all kinds of syntax errors.  The problem happens if you have spaces in your file names.  Thus, this would be a more generally useful batch file:

```
for %%i in (*.wav) do "D:\yourdir\lame.exe" -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05 "%%i" "%%~ni.mp3"
```

Note, in my example I'm also using lower quality for compressing audiobook files for minimum size, and so I can drop the batch file in my wav folder, I put the full path to lame negating the need to set a path environment variable. **The key change is quotes around the filename arguments.**

Comment: I =1'd this because wrapping w/quotes is indeed what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for %%i in (C:\Wavs\*.wav) do lame.exe -V0 -h %%i %%~nI.mp3
```

Just replace `C:\Wavs` with your path.

Comment: I adpated something  similar form another .bat:                      `for %%f in (*.wav) do c:\progra~2\lame\lame.exe -V0 -h "%%f" "%%f.mp3"`                             but it generates inputfile.wav.mp3, which is messy. can i get it to change %%f into from inputfile.wav to inputfile.mp3?

Comment: The `%%~ni` returns the filename without the extension, then you can add the extension you want on the end.